# DropDownListFor from Simple List Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can i implement simple DropDownList without Id.

```
public AddItemModel() 
{
    Types = new SelectList(new []{"Type1", "Type2", "Type3"});
}

public SelectList Types { get; set; }

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AddItem, ???
```

Comment: What you mean by that, show your action how are you passing data to view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a property on your view model to hold the selected value and then you may try this:

```
public AddItemModel() 
{
    var data = new [] { "Type1", "Type2", "Type3" };
    Types = data.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = x,
        Text = x,
    });
}

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Types { get; set; }
public string SelectedType { get; set; }
```

and then in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedType, Model.Types)
```